# Simple Feed Forward Neural Network with no backpropagation yet

Tags: beginner, c, neural-network

The following code is code I wrote in c for a simple neural network with no backpropagation implementation yet. All the header files were put in one file because I am using visual studio which does not have a default for c code just c++ and the seperate header files were causing problems. The goal of this project is to use as minimal amount of external libraries as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE 1

//Beggining of RandomNumberGen.h

unsigned long seed;

//Function that returns the max value that can be stored in a uLong
unsigned long getMaxULongValue()
{
    unsigned long uLongLength = 0;
    uLongLength = ~uLongLength;
    return uLongLength;
}

//Function that returns the max value that can be stored in a uInt
unsigned int getMaxUIntValue()
{
    unsigned int uIntLength = 0;
    uIntLength = ~uIntLength;
    return uIntLength;
}

//Sets the seed for the random number gen
void setRandSeed(unsigned long inputSeed)
{
    seed = inputSeed;
}

//Function to generate pseudo-random ints
unsigned int genRandInt()
{
    seed = (561 * seed + 33) % getMaxULongValue();
    return seed % getMaxUIntValue();
}

//Ending of RandomNumberGen.h

//Beggining of NeuralNetwork.h

float sigmoid(float nodeValue)
{
    return 1 / (1.0 + exp(-nodeValue));
}

void softmax(float*& layer, unsigned int layerLength)
{
    float sumExps = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < layerLength; i++)
    {
        sumExps += exp(layer[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < layerLength; i++)
    {
        layer[i] = exp(layer[i]) / sumExps;
    }
}

struct NeuralNetwork
{
    //Variables to set the number of nodes and layers
    unsigned int numInputNodes;
    unsigned int numHiddenLayers;
    unsigned int numOutputNodes;
    unsigned int* hiddenLayers;

    //Variables to store the values of the nodes
    float* inputNodes;
    float** hiddenNodes;
    float* outputNodes;

    //Variables for the weights between the layers
    float** weightsInput_Hidden;
    float*** weightsHidden_Hidden;
    float** weightsHidden_Output;
};

//function to allocate the memory for the weights and set the weights to random floats
int setWeights(NeuralNetwork* ptr)
{
    //float used to store the result of the formula used to calculate the weight
    float randFloat = 0.0;

    //Allocate the memory for the weightsInput_Hidden double float pointer
    ptr->weightsInput_Hidden = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * ptr->hiddenLayers[0]);

    //if statement to check if the malloc allocation was succesful if not then returns
    if (ptr->weightsInput_Hidden == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->hiddenLayers[0]; i++)
    {
        ptr->weightsInput_Hidden[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * ptr->numInputNodes);

        //if statement to check if the malloc allocation was succesful if not then returns
        if (ptr->weightsInput_Hidden[i] == NULL)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                free(ptr->weightsInput_Hidden[j]);
            }

            return FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->hiddenLayers[0]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ptr->numInputNodes; j++)
        {
            randFloat = (genRandInt() % 100) / 100.0f - 0.5;
            ptr->weightsInput_Hidden[i][j] = randFloat;
        }
    }

    //if statement to check if there is more than one hidden layer
    if ((ptr->numHiddenLayers - 1) > 0)
    {
        ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden = (float***)malloc(sizeof(float**) * (ptr->numHiddenLayers - 1));

        //if statement to check if the malloc allocation was succesful if not then returns
        if (ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden == NULL)
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < ptr->numHiddenLayers; i++)
        {
            ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden[i - 1] = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * ptr->hiddenLayers[i]);

            //if statement to check if the malloc allocation was succesful if not then returns
            if (ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden[i - 1] == NULL)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
                {
                    free(ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden[j]);
                }

                return FAILURE;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < ptr->hiddenLayers[i]; j++)
            {
                ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden[i - 1][j] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * ptr->hiddenLayers[i - 1]);

                //if statement to check if the malloc allocation was succesful if not then returns
                if (ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden[i - 1][j] == NULL)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < (i - 1); k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < j; j++)
                        {
                            free(ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden[k][l]);
                        }
                    }

                    return FAILURE;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < ptr->numHiddenLayers; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ptr->hiddenLayers[i]; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < ptr->hiddenLayers[i - 1]; k++)
                {
                    randFloat = (genRandInt() % 100) / 100.0f - 0.5;
                    ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden[i - 1][j][k] = randFloat;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden = NULL;
    }

    ptr->weightsHidden_Output = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * ptr->numOutputNodes);

    //if statement to check if the malloc allocation was succesful if not then returns
    if (ptr->weightsHidden_Output == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->numOutputNodes; i++)
    {
        ptr->weightsHidden_Output[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * ptr->hiddenLayers[ptr->numHiddenLayers - 1]);

        //if statement to check if the malloc allocation was succesful if not then returns
        if (ptr->weightsHidden_Output[i] == NULL)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                free(ptr->weightsHidden_Output[j]);
            }

            return FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->numOutputNodes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ptr->hiddenLayers[ptr->numHiddenLayers - 1]; j++)
        {
            randFloat = (genRandInt() % 100) / 100.0f - 0.5;
            ptr->weightsHidden_Output[i][j] = randFloat;
        }
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

NeuralNetwork* constructNeuralNetwork(unsigned int numIN, unsigned int* HL, unsigned int numON, unsigned int numHL)
{
    NeuralNetwork* ptr = (NeuralNetwork*)malloc(sizeof(NeuralNetwork));

    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        ptr->numInputNodes = numIN;
        ptr->numHiddenLayers = numHL;
        ptr->numOutputNodes = numON;
        ptr->hiddenLayers = HL;
        ptr->inputNodes = NULL;
        ptr->hiddenNodes = NULL;
        ptr->outputNodes = NULL;
        ptr->weightsInput_Hidden = NULL;
        ptr->weightsHidden_Hidden = NULL;
        ptr->weightsHidden_Output = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //temp loop and allocation to initalize inputNodes with values (delete this loop and allocation when I get the data)
    ptr->inputNodes = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * ptr->numInputNodes);

    if (ptr->inputNodes == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->numInputNodes; i++)
    {
        ptr->inputNodes[i] = (genRandInt() % 100) / 100.0f - 0.5;
    }
    //This marks the end of what needs to be deleted

    setWeights(ptr);

    return ptr;
}


void calcLayer(float*& layer, float* preLayer, float** weightspreLayer_Layer, unsigned int layerLength, unsigned int preLayerLength, unsigned char activationFunction)
{
    layer = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * layerLength);

    if (layer == NULL || preLayer == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < layerLength; i++)
    {
        layer[i] = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < preLayerLength; j++)
        {
            layer[i] += preLayer[j] * weightspreLayer_Layer[i][j];
        }

        //switch statement to determine which activation function to use
        switch (activationFunction)
        {
        case 1: 
            layer[i] = sigmoid(layer[i]);
            break;
        case 2:
            softmax(layer, layerLength);
            break;
        default:
            layer[i] = sigmoid(layer[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Ending of NeuralNetwork.h

int main()
{   
    setRandSeed(52);

    unsigned int randInt = 0;
    float randFloat = 0.0;

    unsigned int* hiddenLayers = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * 3);

    if (hiddenLayers == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        hiddenLayers[i - 1] = i;
    }

    NeuralNetwork* pNetwork = constructNeuralNetwork(5, hiddenLayers, 3, 3);

    pNetwork->hiddenNodes = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * 3);

    if (pNetwork->hiddenNodes == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    pNetwork->outputNodes = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);

    if (pNetwork->outputNodes == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    calcLayer(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[0], pNetwork->inputNodes, pNetwork->weightsInput_Hidden, pNetwork->hiddenLayers[0], pNetwork->numInputNodes, 1);
    calcLayer(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[1], pNetwork->hiddenNodes[0], pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[0], pNetwork->hiddenLayers[1], pNetwork->hiddenLayers[0], 1);
    calcLayer(pNetwork->hiddenNodes[2], pNetwork->hiddenNodes[1], pNetwork->weightsHidden_Hidden[1], pNetwork->hiddenLayers[2], pNetwork->hiddenLayers[1], 1);
    calcLayer(pNetwork->outputNodes, pNetwork->hiddenNodes[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1], pNetwork->weightsHidden_Output, pNetwork->numOutputNodes, pNetwork->hiddenLayers[pNetwork->numHiddenLayers - 1], 2);


    printf("Hidden Node: %f", pNetwork->outputNodes[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `float*& layer` ==> Pray, references? That shouldn't and doesn't compile. `error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token`.

Comment: [`stdlib.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status]) defines two macro constants `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. You do not require your own `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE`. The result of `malloc()` and family need not be casted in C, unlike in C++. There's an implicit conversion to and from a `void *` in C.

Comment: Why are the functions that return the maximum value for a certain integer type not utilizing the macro constants from [`limits.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)?